# Bootstrap control with multiple "data-toggle"

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, binding

Is there a way to assign more than one event to a bootstrap control via "data-toggle"?
For example, let's say I want a button that has a "tooltip" and a "button" toggle assigned
to it.
Tried data-toggle="tooltip button", but only the tooltip worked.

EDIT:

This is easily "workaroundable" with

```
$("#newbtn").toggleClass("active").toggleClass("btn-warning").toggleClass("btn-success");
```

Answer (score 421, accepted):

If you want to add a **modal and a tooltip** without adding javascript or altering the tooltip function, you could also simply wrap an element around it:

```
<span data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="modal">
    <a data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip">
      Hover Me           
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: That is actually the best approach because it defers the concern of presentation to the presentation layer.

Comment: There's some difference though: a `data-toggle="tooltip"` inside the main (button) element will show neatly outside of that element whereas it will overlap with that element if set inside a span wrapper.

Comment: Short, Simple and Smart Solution. Adding Span to Anchor tag doesn't change the design in bootstrap So this is the Perfect Solution for running model and tooltip together.

Comment: this didn't work for me `<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalForm" title="Click to edit row" data-row="0" data-cmid="425" data-id="11788" data-src="1.1.1.1" data-src_desc="null" data-dst="2.2.2.2" data-dst_desc="null" data-protocol="TCP" data-ports="80" data-remarks="none"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to edit row" data-original-title="Click to edit row" data-trigger="hover" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>`

Comment: This approach breaks `btn-group`s (even with `<button>` instead of `<a>` as inner element)

Comment: If the user clicks on the button, then chooses to exit the modal, the tooltip is frozen in place. You can no longer click once to make it disappear. Does anyone know any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 86):

Since tooltip is not initialized automatically, you can make changes in your initialization of the tooltip. I did mine like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: "[data-tooltip=tooltip]",
        container: "body"
    });
});
```

with this markup:

```
<button type="button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-tooltip="tooltip" class="btn btn-info" title="Your tooltip">Text here</button>
```

Notice the `data-tooltip`.

### Update

Or simply,

```
$('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Simplified this with: $('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip();

Comment: Used your Updated answer and was very easy, worked perfectly

Comment: best than wrapping nice solution

Comment: The problem with this (and other solutions in this question right now) is that when you click to open the modal, and then close it, the tooltip shows up again (or stays visible) even though the mouse has left the button. This is very annoying if you e.g. have buttons in a table on every row, as they might block the button above/below. Only way to hide it is to click somewhere outside of the tooltip.

Comment: You may want to use the first JS part as this registers the tooltips on `ready()` event. Without it, the tooltip will be registered whenever the JavaScript file is loaded. Or combine both @RyanCurrah 's code within `ready()` event.

Comment: I love this approach much more than the accepted answer with the wrapper. 
It's very simple as it expands on the HTML5 capacities without overloading the DOM too much. Also in my case the wrapper approach did not seem to work

Answer (score 12):

I managed to solve this issue without the need to change any markup with the following piece of jQuery. I had a similar problem where I wanted a tooltip on a button that was already using data-toggle for a modal. All you will need to do here is add the title to the button.

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"][title]').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 11):

This is the best solution that I just implemented:

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My Tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** *that you anyway need to include regardless of what method you use.*

```
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: This is the cleanest, least obtrusive answer

Answer (score 8):

Not yet. However, it has been suggested that someone add this feature one day.

The following bootstrap Github issue shows a perfect example of what you are wishing for. It is possible- but not without writing your own workaround code at this stage though.

Check it out... :-)

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7011

Comment: Sadly, that issue (#7011) has been declined.

Answer (score 4):

Since Bootstrap forces you to initialize tooltips only through Javascript, I changed `data-toggle="tooltip"` (since it's useless then) to `class="bootstrap-tooltip"` and used this Javascript to initialize my tooltips:

```
$('.bootstrap-tooltip').tooltip();
```

And so I was free to use the `data-toggle` attribute for something else (e.g. `data-toggle="button"`).

Comment: Great. Add HTML too.

Answer (score 3):

I use href to load the modal and leave data-toggle for the tooltip:

```
<a 
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="top"
    title="My Tooltip text!"
    href="javascript:$('#id').modal('show');"
>
+
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for complement @Roman Holzner answer...

In my case, I have a button that shows the tooltip and it should remain disabled until furthermore actions. Using his approach, the modal works even if the button is disabled, because its call is outside the button - I'm in a Laravel blade file, just to be clear :)

```
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-href="{{ $e->id }}">
    <button name="delete" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Excluir Entrada" disabled>
        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

So if you want to show the modal only when the button is active, you should change the order of the tags:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Excluir Entrada" disabled>
    <button name="delete" class="btn btn-default" data-href="{{ $e->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" disabled>
        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

If you want to test it out, change the attribute with a JQuery code:

```
$('button[name=delete]').attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you opening modal on a tag and want show tooltip and if you implement tooltip inside tag it will show tooltip nearby tag. like this

[image]

I will suggest that use div outside a tag and use **"display: inline-block;"**

```html
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Add" 
  style="display:inline-block;"
>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" 
     data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
     onclick="setSelectedRoleId(6)">
         <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
      <span
        class="tags"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="right"
        title="Tooltip text"
      >
        Text
     </span>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice solution using class `.stretched-link`. Button must have a class `.position-relative`. Here is a full working example:

Tooltip must be added to the button otherwise its position will be incorrect.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
/*DEMO*/.btn{margin-left:5rem;margin-top:5rem}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--BUTTON-->
<button class="btn btn-primary position-relative" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip text">
    <span class="stretched-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></span>
    Click Me!
</button>

<!--DEMO MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body">Modal body</div></div></div></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried to use

```html
<span></span>
```

but

```html
<a></a>
```

worked great for me.

Here you are:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Some word here">
<a data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Example">Some info here</a>
</button>
```

Even better, try to wrap the entire button (that uses popover) with a div:

```html
<div data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Something">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Some word here">
Button label
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice tip with the outer div. Problem with the padding of button is now avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the toggle needed by adding 2 lines of javascript the usual HTML attributes

```js
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[tooltip="true"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
```

Now, instead of `data-bs-toggle='tooltip'`, use `tooltip="true"`.

Finally, your Html would look like :

```
<button tooltip="true" data-bs-placement="top" title="Your tooltip here"/>
```

Working Demo :

```js
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[tooltip="true"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>



<button id="someid" style="margin:34px; height:33px !important" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-1 w-25 h-25  " tooltip="true" data-bs-placement="top" title="This button opens modal and also displays a tootip using different names for data-bs-toggle and initiating them with js" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      <i  class="fa fa-cog"></i> 
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

et Voila  !

Answer (score 0):

HTML (ejs dianmic web page): this is a table list of all users and from nodejs generate the table. NodeJS provide dinamic "<%= user.id %>". simply change for any value like "54"

```
<span type="button" data-href='/admin/user/del/<%= user.id %>' class="item" 
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm_delete">
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" data- 
     toggle="modal">
       <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i> 
    </div>
</span>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
         data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticModalLabel">Static Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> This is a static modal, backdrop click will not close it. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <form method="POST" class="btn-ok">
            <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Confirm"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end modal static -->
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#confirm_delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('action', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My Tooltip text!">+</a>
```