# How do I have Multiple Tooltips for one image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I would like to have three different tooltips appear when I hover over an image without nesting div's.

This code does work:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
     <div id="tooltip1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="keyword1" >
     <div id="tooltip2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="keyword2">
     <div id="tooltip3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="keyword3">
     <img src="/img/600x336.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></div></div></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is something like this with "data-content" maybe being "id:position:title":

```
<div id="tooltips1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="tip1,top,keyword1:tip2,left,keyword2:etc;">
    <img src="img/600x336.jpg" />
</div>
```

Reference: [Bootstrap control with multiple "data-toggle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402390/bootstrap-control-with-multiple-data-toggle)

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and my javascript is very limited.

Comment: What is wrong with the earlier approach?

Comment: In webkit browsers the tooltips are grouping wrong and in firefox they pay no attention to bottom-left or top-left or any diagonal positioning.