# Radio buttons and multiple collapsing elements with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm running into a similar issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402390/bootstrap-control-with-multiple-data-toggle), in that I need the `data-toggle` option on a button to take two parameters.

I'm making a multi-card collapse with radio buttons. I.e., we have three options. When an option is selected, any open cards are collapsed, and the selected card is un-collapsed. What I'd also like is the selected button to stay selected.

```
<button href="#option1" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="collapse">Option 1</button>
<button href="#option2" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="collapse">Option 2</button>
<button href="#option3" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="collapse">Option 3</button>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="option1" class="collapse panel" data-parent="#parent">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Details of option 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="option2" class="collapse panel" data-parent="#parent">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Details of option 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="option3" class="collapse panel" data-parent="#parent">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Details of option 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trouble is, you can only specify one option to `data-toggle`, so when the buttons are clicked at the moment, they don't go into their active state, which would happen if I could specify something like `data-toggle="collapse button"`

Unfortunately, all the searching I've done for two data toggle parameters only leads to people asking about adding tooltips to buttons. Is there any way in bootstrap of changing the button's state while also using it to collapse elements?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, I'm using your code and the button clicked is staying in the active state...

Comment: I have just noticed a spelling mistake. `btn-primary-outline` rather than `btn-outline-primary`. Are your buttons empty by default, then filled in on clicking?

Comment: yes, when I load the html no buttons are initially active by default. Would you like a JsFiddle example?