# Can I add data-toggle="modal" and data-toggle="dropdown" in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4.1.x

I tried the way that is already described in an answer to this question.

[Bootstrap control with multiple “data-toggle”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402390/bootstrap-control-with-multiple-data-toggle)

**But this way is not working**.

Is there **any other way** of using ***data-toggle="modal"*** and ***data-toggle="dropdown"*** on a same link.

```
<li class="dropdown" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>My Menu</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="mang_store">First Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>`
```

Comment: You have to decide, what should the link do when you click on it? Open a dropdown or a modal.

Comment: Right...doesn't make sense having both on  one element

Comment: when hover on a link then I want dropdown and when click then I want modal @Chay22

Comment: @charlietfl I want both ... Its requirements please tell me the way if you hav any

Answer (score 0):

You can always use javascript to toggle the first event i.e data-toggle="modal" and/or data-toggle="dropdown".

Just use one event on click and put in the javascript the other event to trigger in X seconds.

Comment: how is it possible?